# What does "position" refer to?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Neo and Seraph are discussing about backdoor, a type of door that can be used to
access nearly any part of the Matrix.:

> Neo: How do they work?
>
> Seraph: A code is hidden in tumblers. One **position** opens a lock
> and another
> **position** opens one of these doors.

What does "position" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tumblers" are parts of mechanical locks, most commonly executed as spring loaded pins, but they may also be discs or wafers.

They encode information, in a way, because a lock contains several of them that need to be actuated in a specific fashion to get a desired action; more trivially, e.g. in a traditional pin tumbler lock, each pin tumbler needs to be pushed to an exact height to release the lock (that is why keys have alternating high spots and low cuts).

Since backdoors in the Matrix can be visualized as actual doors, in sounds reasonable that the access mechanism is visualized as a mechanical lock as well. The "tumblers" in this lock allow for several configurations, so what information is released depends on the position you slide them into. So the "position" would refer to the configuration the actuated tumblers are in, which in real life would correspond to the position of the key in the lock.

This is somewhat common sense rather than something I remember from the movie, but Valorum in the comments suggested that I should make in an answer, and I trust his judgement here.